# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (code = 1) when posting a notification with Notification Center

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, exc-bad-access, nsnotificationcenter

I have a view controller with this method:

```
- (void)getImages
{
   if (self.myEntities != nil) {
      if (self.myEntities.count > 0) {
         if (self.imagesDownloader == nil) {
            self.imagesDownloader = [[ImagesDownloader alloc] initWithListener];
         }
      }

      for (MyEntity *myEntity in self.myEntities) {
         if (![myEntity.imageUrl isEqualToString:@""] && (myEntity.imageUrl != nil)) {
            [self.imagesDownloader getImageFromServiceUrl:myEntity.imageUrl];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And `ImagesDownloader` is an `NSObject` subclass like this:

```
@implementation ImagesDownloader

- (id)initWithListener
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      [self registerNotifications];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)registerNotifications
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                   name:@"getImageDidFinish"
                                                 object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(getImageDidFinish:)
                                                name:@"getImageDidFinish"
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)getImageFromServiceUrl:(NSString *)imageUrl
{
   GetImage *getImage = [[GetImage alloc] init];
   [getImage queryServiceWithImageUrl:imageUrl];
}

// More instance methods

@end
```

In turn, `GetImage` is another `NSObject` subclass that calls a RESTful web service by using an `NSURLConnection` object, and then, in its `connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate method, it posts the notification the `imagesDownloader` object is observing via Notification Center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getImageDidFinish"
                                                    object:nil
                                                  userInfo:serviceInfoDict];
```

This is the call where I sometimes get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The scenario is like this: the view controller is loaded (it is pushed into a navigation stack) and `getImages` is called. Right now, its `self.myEntities` has 3 objects, so `self.imagesDownloader` is initialized and call 3 times to `getImageFromServiceUrl`. The service is called 3 times as well, and in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, the notification is posted the 3 times with no error.

But I then go back and forth the view controller, and it is loaded again and same calls made. But this time, I get the error the 2nd time the notification is going to be posted from `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. I don't undersatnd why, what could I be missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are these `self.myEntities` ? Core Data entities ?

Comment: Does `ImagesDownloader` have a `dealloc` that removes it as an observer?  If not, that seems a likely source of trouble.

Comment: @Randy Yes, they are managed objects

Comment: I've had some issues using `NSNotificationCenter`and CoreData. Can you try that :
`for (MyEntity *myEntity in self.myEntities) {
         if (![myEntity.imageUrl isEqualToString:@""] && (myEntity.imageUrl != nil)) {
NSString *imageUrl = myEntity.imageUrl
            [self.imagesDownloader getImageFromServiceUrl:imageUrl];
         }
      }`

Comment: @PhillipMills No, it hadn't. I've just added it and now it seems to work... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PhillipMills said, adding this to `ImagesDownloader` seems to solve the problem:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```